# Why the excecSQL not accept * in the statement?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm working on an android project and I have to delete all records in my table:

```
 public void deleteAll(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    String req="delete * from "+ TABLE_ENIGME;
    db.execSQL(req);
}
```

But when I call my function **deleteAll** this exception is reveled :

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "*": syntax error: delete * from enigme2
```

So why " * " is innapropriate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please have a look at http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html.
Delete does not accept wildcard.
Use

```
Delete From <table name>
```

instead

Answer (score 4):

mostly because thats not valid sql syntax.  The just omit the star and do

```
delete from enigme2;
```

Comment: I have already declared TABLE_ENIGME as :                 private static final String TABLE_ENIGME = "enigme2";

Answer (score 2):

It's inappropriate because it isn't valid SQL syntax. The `*` is used to denote "all columns" (when SELECTing). Since the DELETE statement is removing entire rows stating "all columns" is meaningless, as it removes the values from all columns for that row by default.